# Simple url rewriting with passed get parameters, turns server in to Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

First of all, I have simple .htaccess rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And PHP side script for AJAX calls:

```
$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            $scriptName = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

            $commandArray = array_diff_assoc($requestURI,$scriptName);
            $commandArray = array_values($commandArray);

            $parameters = array_slice($commandArray,1);
                require_once('front/ajax.php');
```

Url witch returns Internal Server Error is:

```
domainname.com/ajax/json/login/dr/?druid=439985&name=Gatis&data=WITH_LONG_JSON_STRING
```

Everything works fine, until I reach `&data` parameter, which consists with long JSON string - http://pastebin.com/6C8AbJGd. Is there any way for workaround?

Comment: Why not use POST instead of GET?

Comment: Yes it is `500` error, and why I`m not using `POST`, because those parameters are from outer resource(API)

Comment: @user3428269 Thanks for updating! Although `500` errors usually have a PHP Error that would be visible if you turned on the errors or logging; that would be some key info!

Comment: @MackieeE I turned error logging on: And I get only one error `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library - libmemcached.so ...`